# can't change activity on xamarin android interface razor page error java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android

Hi guys please help me i read all of stack and anywhere you think but can't solved my problem.

My app project is written with xamarin android , razor page.

I have inter face in xamarin android for calling action between razor page and activity.

I want to change activity in razor interface xamarin but have problem ! its work fine on android 6 or lower ! but don't work on android 7 or higher !

This is my log:

> `--------- beginning of crash 08-07 13:37:27.134
>   E/AndroidRuntime(10460): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 08-07 13:37:27.134
>   E/AndroidRuntime(10460): Process: PharmApp.PharmApp, PID: 10460 08-07
>   13:37:27.134 E/AndroidRuntime(10460): java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 08-07 13:37:27.134
>   E/AndroidRuntime(10460): at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779) 08-07
>   13:37:27.134 E/AndroidRuntime(10460): Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 08-07 13:37:27.134
>   E/AndroidRuntime(10460): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native
>   Method) 08-07 13:37:27.134 E/AndroidRuntime(10460): at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
>   08-07 13:37:27.134 E/AndroidRuntime(10460): ... 1 more 08-07
>   13:37:27.134 E/AndroidRuntime(10460): Caused by:
>   android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.NotSupportedException:
>   Could not activate JNI Handle 0xffeee828 (key_handle 0xc02603b) of
>   Java type 'md51b37e36ad3b09170e292587940676a4a/MainActivity' as
>   managed type 'PharmApp.MainActivity'. --->
>   System.DllNotFoundException: /system/lib/libsqlite.so 08-07
>   13:37:27.134 E/AndroidRuntime(10460): at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   SQLite.SQLite3:Open (byte[],intptr&,int,intptr) 08-07 13:37:27.134
>   E/AndroidRuntime(10460): at SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor
>   (System.String databasePath, SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags openFlags,
>   System.Boolean storeDateTimeAsTicks) [0x0003c] in
>   <1fdca804045a4bdfb6367b61a9a9bc1d>:0  08-07 13:37:27.134
>   E/AndroidRuntime(10460): at SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor
>   (System.String databasePath, System.Boolean storeDateTimeAsTicks)
>   [0x00000] in <1fdca804045a4bdfb6367b61a9a9bc1d>:0  08-07 13:37:27.134
>   E/AndroidRuntime(10460): at PharmApp.Models.DbPharmApp..ctor ()
>   [0x00028] in <1fdca804045a4bdfb6367b61a9a9bc1d>:0  08-07 13:37:27.134
>   E/AndroidRuntime(10460): at PharmApp.MainActivity..ctor () [0x00000]
>   in <1fdca804045a4bdfb6367b61a9a9bc1d>:0  08-07 13:37:27.134
>   E/AndroidRuntime(10460): at (wrapper dynamic-method)
>   System.Object:8e2c4fc2-c360-4e79-83eb-896d1e95d294 (intptr,object[])
>   08-07 13:37:27.134 E/AndroidRuntime(10460): at
>   Java.Interop.TypeManager.n_Activate (System.IntPtr jnienv,
>   System.IntPtr jclass, System.IntPtr typename_ptr, System.IntPtr
>   signature_ptr, System.IntPtr jobject, System.IntPtr parameters_ptr)
>   [0x000de] in <22580c563fd3455f82bcff76b9141fa3>:0  08-07 13:37:27.134
>   E/AndroidRuntime(10460):` `--- End of inner exception stack trace ---`

And this is my code :

```
[Export]
[JavascriptInterface]
public void RedirectIndex()
{
    try
    {
        activity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            var intent = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity));
            intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(activity, e.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Noticed there is such an exception: `System.DllNotFoundException: /system/lib/libsqlite.so`.

It is possible that you're using the old `SQlite` version which is not compatible with Android 7.0 and higher version, if you installed the some `SQLite` relative library, please refer to this doc: [Preparing for Native Library Linking Changes in Android N](https://blog.xamarin.com/preparing-for-native-library-linking-changes-in-android-n/), and try to update your library as the doc suggested.